# Ошибка сборки проекта

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Подскажите пожалуйста куда смотреть. В Gradle добавил строку compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0' и началось...

Ошибка:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.2.2\d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b\jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
    File2: C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.2.2\285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113\jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
    File3: C:\Users\USER\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.2.2\3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6\jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0' 
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вбиваем ошибку в гугл

> [Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Duplicate%20files%20copied%20in%20APK%20META-INF%2FLICENSE)

2. Идём по одной из первых [ссылок](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31912566/3212712)
3. Согласно инфе из неё добавляем исключение файлов, вызывающих конфликт так (добавить надо в `build.gradle`):

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```